# Logging SMTP connections with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, smtpd

Python newbie here. I'm writing an SMTP server using Twisted and twisted.mail.smtp. I'd like to log incoming connections and possibly dump them when there are too many concurrent connections. Basically, I want ConsoleMessageDelivery.connectionMade() method to be called in the following, when a new connection is made:

```
class ConsoleMessageDelivery:
    implements(smtp.IMessageDelivery)

    def connectionMade(self):
        # This never gets called

    def receivedHeader(self, helo, origin, recipients):
        myHostname, clientIP = helo
        headerValue = "by %s from %s with ESMTP ; %s" % (myHostname, clientIP, smtp.rfc822date())
        # email.Header.Header used for automatic wrapping of long lines
        return "Received: %s" % Header(headerValue)

    def validateFrom(self, helo, origin):
        # All addresses are accepted
        return origin

    def validateTo(self, user):
        if user.dest.local == "console":
            return lambda: ConsoleMessage()
        raise smtp.SMTPBadRcpt(user)

class ConsoleMessage:
    implements(smtp.IMessage)

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def eomReceived(self):
        return defer.succeed(None)

    def connectionLost(self):
        # There was an error, throw away the stored lines
        self.lines = None

class ConsoleSMTPFactory(smtp.SMTPFactory):
    protocol = smtp.ESMTP

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        smtp.SMTPFactory.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        self.delivery = ConsoleMessageDelivery()

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = smtp.SMTPFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)
        p.delivery = self.delivery
        return p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connectionMade` is part of `twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol`, not part of `twisted.mail.smtp.IMessageDelivery`.  There's no code anywhere in the mail server implementation that cares about a `connectionMade` method on a message delivery implementation.

A better place to put *per connection* logic is in the factory.  And specifically, a good way to approach this is with a factory *wrapper*, to isolate the logic about connection limits and logging from the logic about servicing SMTP connections.

Twisted comes with a few factory wrappers.  A couple in particular that might be interesting to you are `twisted.protocols.policies.LimitConnectionsByPeer` and `twisted.protocols.policies.LimitTotalConnectionsFactory`.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any documentation explaining `twisted.protocols.policies`.  Fortunately, it's not too complicated.  Most of the factories in the module wrap another arbitrary factory to add some piece of behavior.  So, for example, to use `LimitConnectionsByPeer`, you do something like this:

```
from twisted.protocols.policies import LimitConnectionsByPeer
...
factory = ConsoleSMTPFactory()
wrapper = LimitConnectionsByPeer(ConsoleSMTPFactory(...))
reactor.listenTCP(465, wrapper)
```

This is all that's needed to get `LimitConnectionsByPeer` to do its job.

There's only a little bit more complexity involved in writing your own wrapper.  First, subclass `WrappingFactory`.  Then implement whichever methods you're interested in customizing.  In your case, if you want to reject connections from a certain IP, that would mean overriding `buildProtocol`.  Then, unless you also want to customize the protocol that is constructed (which you don't in this case), call the base implementation and return its result.  For example:

```
from twisted.protocols.policies import WrappingFactory

class DenyFactory(WrappingFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, clientAddress):
        if clientAddress.host == '1.3.3.7':
            # Reject it
            return None
         # Accept everything else
         return WrappingFactory.buildProtocol(self, clientAddress)
```

These wrappers stack, so you can combine them as well:

```
from twisted.protocols.policies import LimitConnectionsByPeer
...
factory = ConsoleSMTPFactory()
wrapper = LimitConnectionsByPeer(DenyFactory(ConsoleSMTPFactory(...)))
reactor.listenTCP(465, wrapper)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think I understand it now, but I'm seeing a couple issues. One is that I get an "exceptions.TypeError: 'IPv4Address' object does not support indexing" error for both LimitConnectionsByPeer and for your DenyFactory example. I'm using Python 2.7; is this compatible with Python 3 only? Also, the LimitTotalConnectionsFactory() appears to take no arguments.

Comment: Oops.  I'm living in the past.  Updating the example now.

Comment: LimitTotalConnectionsFactory (which is not the same as LimitConnectionsByPeer, of course) is, for some reason, not a WrappingFactory, though it clearly should be.  Instead, it's just a ServerFactory with some extra behavior, so it's harder to combine it with other factories.  You could use it and LimitConnectionsByPeer as examples to guide you in building your own WrappingFactory subclass that has total-connection limiting behavior, though.  And perhaps also file a feature request against Twisted asking for a WrappingFactory-based version of LimitTotalConnectionsFactory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I'm stuck with one final part, which I've posted at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199412/cleanup-of-resources-with-the-smtp-module-of-twisted-python) concerning cleanup of resources. Any help would be greatly appreciated!